# finding duplicate columns along joining data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find duplicates in a table column only if the row is also a child of another table ex:

table 1 columns

```
id
Type
```

table 2 columns

```
id
table1Id
table3Id
```

Sample Data:

```
table 1:
    id    Type
    1      aType
    2      myType
    3      myType
    4      aType
    5      myType
    6      aType

table 2:
    id    table1Id    table3Id
    1        1            1
    2        2            1
    3        4            2
    4        5            1
    5        6            2
```

Results I'd like: (rows in table1 with same Type and table3Id)

```
table1Id  table1Type table3Id
   2        myType     1
   5        myType     1
   4        aType      2
   6        aType      2
```

query I tried

```
select table1.id as table1Id, table1.type as table1Type, table2.table3Id as table3Id 
from table1, table2 
inner join table1 a on table1.Type = a.Type
where a.id <> table1.id and table1.Type = "myType" and table1.id = table2.table1Id
```

The above query give me an error "unknown column table1.Type in on clause"

Comment: Can you edit your question with sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if the query is correct, but you are getting the error because of the comma in the from clause.  Here is an easy rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You can fix your problem directly by using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select table1.id as table1Id, table1.type as table1Type, table2.table3Id as table3Id 
from table1 cross join
     table2 inner join
     table1 a 
     on table1.Type = a.Type
where a.id <> table1.id and table1.Type = 'myType' and
      table1.id = table2.table1Id;
```

It is better to put the `JOIN` conditions in an `ON` clause:

```
select t1.id as table1Id, t1.type as table1Type, t2.table3Id 
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.table1Id inner join
     table1 a 
     on t1.Type = a.Type and a.id <> t1.id
where t1.Type = 'myType' ;
```

That fixes the syntax error -- which is your question.  If this doesn't deliver what you expect, then ask another question with sample data, desired results, and a clearer description of the logic.

Comment: that query fixed the syntax error, but gave me hundreds of duplicates of the same row where table1Id, table1Type, and table3Id were all the same. With 500,000 results

Comment: @rodney757 . .  . Your original question was about the syntax error.  As suggested in my answer, ask another question if you want to fix the logic.